# What is the security hole in tmpfile and how does tmpfile_s solve it?

Tags: c, winapi, visual-c++, temporary-files

What is the security hole in [`tmpfile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8x7sakw.aspx) and how does [`tmpfile_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3dz6009.aspx) solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it appears to fall under the "Enhanced error reporting" category of upgrades to the Windows CRT. In this case, it basically means that it will return a status value and fill out a pre-given `FILE` pointer, rather than just returning a `FILE` pointer.

I doubt there was actually a security flaw with `tmpfile`, more that Microsoft were bringing the implementation of it to the same standards as other functions in their CRT without breaking API compatibility with a standard CRT, as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ef0s5kh.aspx.